# Which design pattern is better for data pipelines: batches or one at a time?

Tags: pipelines

I come from a software engineering background and have a firm knowledge of best design patterns in that world, but with data science I feel like I'm making elementary design pattern mistakes.

One thing I've noticed is that I often write code like this:

`mediumInputArray => someFilterFn => someMapFn => someOtherMapFn => someOtherFilterFn => someFinalFn`

All of those functions in that pipeline accept arrays, so method 2 doesn't start on the batch until method 1 finishes with all the array elements, and so one.

It seems often mediumInputArray evolves into hugeInputArray and I need to shard things to run on many machines. At that point dealing with batches becomes brittle and cumbersome.

Is it a better design pattern to just write a pipeline that operates on one atomic entity, and then have 1 job run from start to end?

What would be some design patterns that are related to this?

Is there a good book on advanced data science design patterns?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, this depends on the exact task that you run. Can you specify what exactly slows down in your pipeline, when and where?

Comment: @André the slowdown happens simply as N increases. At a certain point, I end up  wanting to run across machines and instead of dealing with batches I find it easier to operate one item at a time, and so rewrite my pipeline (and then I can still do a similar pattern with items.apply(pipeline).) I wasn't sure if it was best practice to make pipelines operate on one entity and then do the mapping at the root level or whether to have every stage operate on an array.